# error when uploading a aspx website

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config, hosting

when i host my website on my local machine on IIS 7 my website runs correctly, but when i upload the website to my hosting space online the error:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="20"/>
```

(comes up in red)

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

comes up. could you guys please help me out?

Notes i use multiple web.config files and no i cannot delete them

Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The clue is here: "This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS."

Depending on who your hosting provider is, check that your website is running as a Web Application.

Answer (score 0):

The  tag is allowed only at the root level. If you are using multiple web.config's ensure that you haven't copied this tag into any other config file.

Also ensure that your virtual directory root is marked as an application.